# How do i install MySQLdb for python 3.4 - pip does not work even though i have Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

This is the error that is returned when i try the command pip install MySQL-python for python 3.4, any idea on how to fix this

I have installed Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013 from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784

```
C:\Windows\System32>pip install MySQL-python
Downloading/unpacking MySQL-python
  Running setup.py (path:C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Matthew\M
ySQL-python\setup.py) egg_info for package MySQL-python

Installing collected packages: MySQL-python
  Running setup.py install for MySQL-python
    building '_mysql' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).

    Complete output from command C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools, t
okenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Matthew\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip_build_Matthew\\M
ySQL-python\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).re
ad().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Matthe
w\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-db8fnhk5-record\install-record.txt --single-version-ext
ernally-managed --compile:
    running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build\lib.win32-3.4

copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4

creating build\lib.win32-3.4\MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\MySQLdb

creating build\lib.win32-3.4\MySQLdb\constants

copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\MySQLdb\constants

copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\MySQLdb\constants

copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\MySQLdb\constants


copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\MySQLdb\constants

copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\MySQLdb\constants

copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\MySQLdb\constants

copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\MySQLdb\constants

running build_ext

building '_mysql' extension

error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Use
rs\\Matthew\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip_build_Matthew\\MySQL-python\\setup.py';ex
ec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'
), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-
db8fnhk5-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
 failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Matth
ew\MySQL-python
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\Matthew\pip\pip.log

C:\Windows\System32>
```

Comment: When I find pip doesn't work, I fall back to using easy_install.

Comment: @user590028 How would i do that - do i need to install anything new - what command to use to install MySQL

Comment: You'll need Visual Studio 2010 to build extensions for Python 3.4. The [current version of MySQL-python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5) does not support Python 3. [Mysqlclient-python](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python) does. Unofficial binaries are at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient